# What's the difference between Number.somepropertyormethod and Number().somepropertyormethod?

Tags: javascript

So the following works:

```
alert(Number().toString.call(1));
```

But this does not work:

```
alert(Number.toString.call(1));
```

Furthermore, the following works:

```
alert(Number.prototype.constructor(1));
```

But this does not work:

```
alert(Number().prototype.constructor(1));
```

Why do we need the parentheses following Number in the first example, and why must we omit the parentheses in the second example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Number` is a constructor object. Called as a function, it allows you to create new number instances.  `Number()` returns the number `0`.  Number instances have various properties and methods, including `toString()` and `toExponential()` (for example).  The following two bits of syntax have identical meanings:

```
Number().toString.call(1);
(0).toString.call(1);
```

The `Number` object also has properties of its own.  One special property is the `prototype` property.  This is basically a template for new number instances.  All properties that exist on `Number.prototype` exist on number instances as well.  So we can add a third bit of identical code to the above two:

```
Number.prototype.toString.call(1);
```

Number instances, however, do not have the `prototype` property, so you can't access `Number().prototype`. On the other hand, they do have a `constructor` property, which returns the object that created them, i.e. the Number object. You can then access `prototype` on this. So our fourth identical bit of code:

```
Number().constructor.prototype.toString.call(1);
```

Hopefully this has clarified the relationship between the `Number` object and number instances.  As a last note, all the above bits of code are identical to this, the obviously correct way to do this:

```
(1).toString();
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try to check the following :

```
alert(typeof Number());//number
alert(typeof Number);//function
```

it is normal that they have different behaviors, they mean different things

Answer (score 0):

I believe in your example Number is a class and Number() is a constructor call which returns an instance of the Number class.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some tips, you seem very confused

- The constructor function (Number) doesn't have a property called toString. It does have a property called prototype which allows instances to look at that object if a property isn't defined in the object itself.
- Number() returns an instance, that does have a property called toString through the prototype chain (from Number.prototype.toString). Those instances do not have a prototype property

---

```
// So the following works, you're calling the toString Method of Number.prototype 
// and passing 1 as its context
alert(Number().toString.call(1));


// But this does not work:
// Number (the constructor) does not have property called toString, FAIL
alert(Number.toString.call(1));
```